# Corcel - Set featured image for saved post

Tags: php, laravel, corcel

I am using ["jgrossi/corcel": "3.0.0"](https://github.com/corcel/corcel), `Laravel 6.16.0` and `PHP 7.4.1`

I would like to add a featured image to my `saved()`-post

I tried to create a wordpress post the following way:

```
        $post = new Post();
        $post->post_title = $title;
        $post->post_content = $msg;
        $post->image = "http://www.urlToImage.com/image.png"; //does not work
        $post->save();
```

When trying the above function I get the following exception:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `wp_posts` (`post_title`, `post_content`, `post_type`, `post_status`, `ping_status`, `post_author`, `image`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_modified`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_date`)
```

Any suggestions how to save a post and set the featured image?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: The `wp_posts` table don't have the image field. In WP, images are stored as posts with different post types. The easier way to do this is the WP way, see this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41300

Answer (score 0):

i solved it using the following method

```
$post = Post::create([
            'post_title'=>$request->input('title'),
            'post_content' => $request->input('content'),
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            "post_type" => "post"
        ]);
     
        PostMeta::create([
            'post_id'=>$post->ID,
            'meta_key'=>'_thumbnail_ext_url',
            'meta_value'=>$image
        ]);
```

to use external url for a post i installed this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-url-as-post-featured-image-thumbnail/?